# What is the name for this parameter of polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, terminology

Could you please help me?

In the polynomial $p(x) = a_k x^k + a_{k+1} x^{k+1} + ... + a_n x^n$ ($a_k, a_n \neq 0$), we say that $n$ is a "degree" of this polynomial, deg $p = n$.

Is there any special word or notation for $k$?

I did not find the answer with the help of the Google.

Comment: The valuation.....

Comment: Could I write val $p = k$?

Comment: It is the *degree* of the polynomial. See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial

Comment: @user160436: you don't need a written authorization by some higher authority.

Comment: It is sometimes called the **low degree** of the polynomial.

Comment: Thanks guys, I also found that it is called "the order of the polynomial considered as a power series, that is, the degree of its non-zero term of lowest degree".

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no special name for $k$.

$k$ is the order$^1$ of the zero at $x=0$ (because $a_k\neq0$).

You could say that $k$ is the minimum degree of all [monimials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial) comprising $p$, but that is quite long-winded.  In particular if you are nor referring to monomials anywhere else.

Also $k$ is the index of the lowest or first (by degree) non-zero coefficient of $p$.

In the context of valued fields it can be used to define a non-trivial [valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)) of $p$, but outside that context this term might be quite confusing or has not been defined.

$^1$ Where order = 0 means that 0 is not a zero of $p$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.